# Kafka Topics "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to get offsets by times in 60001ms"

Tags: apache-kafka

In our single zookeeper - single broker kafka cluster, we are getting "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to get offsets by times in 60001ms" while trying to access older topics. Surprisingly, newly created topics are working fine. Stoping and starting zookeeper and broker did not help.

Any idea on what root cause of above error and resolution steps please?

Trying to access old topics.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "old"? Kafka deletes data after a week, but that wouldn't cause this error... Describe the topic. Are the replicas/partitions trying to use an invalid broker id?